# ASP.NET MVC action does not recognise post json data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, forms, model-binding

I have this form with 3 fields that i want to pass to a controller action:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" name="frmUserData" id="frmUserData">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtlitm">Item Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlitm" name="txtlitm">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtmcu">Branch Plant (filter):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtmcu" name="txtmcu">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtlocn">Location (filter):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtlocn" name='txtlocn'>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnGO">Search</button>
</form>
```

**My javascript:
Version 1:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify($('#frmUserData').serializeArray()),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: action,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $(dataContainer).html(data);
        $(what).hide();
    }
```

**Version 2:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: '{"frmData":' + JSON.stringify($('#frmUserData').serializeArray()) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: action,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $(dataContainer).html(data);
        $(what).hide();
    }
```

**My MVC Action:**

```
public PartialViewResult GetAvailability(FormModel frmData)
{
    var vm = Bll.GetAvailabilityWithHolds(frmData.txtlitm, frmData.txtmcu, frmData.txtlocn);
    return PartialView(new GetAvailabilityModel{Availability = vm});
}
```

**My Form class:**

```
public class FormModel
{
    public string txtlitm { get; set; }
    public string txtmcu { get; set; }
    public string txtlocn { get; set; }
}
```

No matter what i do, i get null values in controller action.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this?  You don't need to use Json, you can go with standard form-encoding

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: $('#frmUserData').serialize(),
url: action,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data) {
    $(dataContainer).html(data);
    $(what).hide();
}
```

I can't test any of these fixes, but what about trying this to fix your original solution:

Attempt 1

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: '{"frmData":' + JSON.stringify($('#frmUserData').serializeArray()[0]) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: action,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $(dataContainer).html(data);
       $(what).hide();
}
```

Attempt 2

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify($('#frmUserData').serializeArray()[0]),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: action,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $(dataContainer).html(data);
        $(what).hide();
}
```

Comment: It works with your solution.But what if i wanted to use json. For this project i can live with just serialize.

Comment: I can't test without a setting up a sample project, but have a go at the alternate solutions in the answer